# Elementor Custom Query Filter - Filter Blog Posts by Tags and Display in Custom Post Type

Tags: filter, elementor

Any ideas how to prepare custom query filter in Elementor for this?

I have Custom Post Type "hotel" with ACF field "Country" and Blog Posts with pharse name of country in title.

I want display blog posts with conuntry name in Single CPT Hotel Posts.
Any ideas?

I checked examples from elementor website but I don't how to prepare it.